# System.IO.FileNotFoundException when running Unit Test under Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, c++-cli

I am getting a System.IO.FileNotFoundException whenever I try to run my unit tests under visual studio. I have made sure that all the dependencies are resolved but the error seems to be with the testclass itself which can't be loaded.

Unable to get type deotests.MockTest, deo.tests. Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

```
[TestClass]
public ref class MmimTest
{
private:
    TestContext^ testContextInstance;

public: 
    /// <summary>
    ///Gets or sets the test context which provides
    ///information about and functionality for the current test run.
    ///</summary>
    property Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting::TestContext^ TestContext
    {
        Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting::TestContext^ get()
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        System::Void set(Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting::TestContext^ value)
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    };

    #pragma region Additional test attributes
    //
    //You can use the following additional attributes as you write your tests:
    //
    //Use ClassInitialize to run code before running the first test in the class
    //[ClassInitialize()]
    //static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext^ testContext) {};
    //
    //Use ClassCleanup to run code after all tests in a class have run
    //[ClassCleanup()]
    //static void MyClassCleanup() {};
    //
    //Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test
    //[TestInitialize()]
    //void MyTestInitialize() {};
    //
    //Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
    //[TestCleanup()]
    //void MyTestCleanup() {};
    //

    #pragma endregion 

    [TestMethod]
    void TestMethod1()
    {
    };
};
```

}

Comment: @user4581301; I've removed the C++-Cli badge. It had to be simply C++.

Comment: Your code is blatantly C++/CLI, neither C++ nor C++/CX.

Comment: @Duplicator This is a code snippet taken from  native C++ test project created under VS9.

Comment: Well, then this being C++ is a very transparent lie propagated by MS.